# How to get the fully qualified path for a file in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, path

I am using the `Shell.Application` object, which allows me to script creation of a zip file.

But in order for this to work, I need to full path of the zip file.  `File.zip` doesn't work.  I need `c:\the\full\path\file.zip`, even if the script is running within the same directory where the file is found.

How can I get the full path of a file in [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)?

Something like the `%~fI` expansion in the cmd.exe shell.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On [Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(VS.85).aspx), there's a method called [GetAbsolutePathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx1xa64f(VS.85).aspx) that does this.

This is what worked for me:

```
Dim folderName
folderName = "..\.."

Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim fullpath
fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(folderName)

WScript.Echo "folder spec: " & folderName
WScript.Echo "fullpath:    " & fullpath
```

Answer (score 6):

For example

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFile= objArgs(0)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
WScript.Echo objFile.Path
```

on command line

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo myscript.vbs myfile
```