# vbscript pass the current directory as named argument

Tags: command-line, vbscript, command-line-arguments, wsh

I'm trying to pass the working directory to vbscript as a named argument.  The system normally expands "." to the current path, but when I check the named argument I just get the string "."

Here's the command line:

```
    cscript myscript.vbs /a:"first arg" /b:second /c:.
```

Here's the script:

```
    dim args : set args = wscript.arguments.named
    wscript.echo args.item("a")
    wscript.echo args.item("b")
    wscript.echo args.item("c")
```

Here's the output:

```
    first arg
    second
    .
```

Comment: You will not be able to pass in a dot and expect it to resolve to the full path as the dot comes through as a string.   Take a look here as you can get the full path inside your script.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129327/how-to-get-the-fully-qualified-path-for-a-file-in-vbscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo fso.GetAbsolutePathName(args("c"))
```

Or you could use `/c:"%CD%"` instead of `/c:.`.

If you always want to know the current directory, you don't need to pass it as an argument, though. Simply use

```
cwd = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
```